# case statement logic in informatica?

Tags: case, decode, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Could anyone help me to solve this problem in Informatica, I am new to Informatica, I want to build `case` statement logic in Informatica but the `case` is not available in Informatica,  how to use `case` statements.

```
CASE
    WHEN E_ID = EMP_ID AND F_NAME = FIRST_NAME AND CITY = LOCATION THEN 'REJECT'
    WHEN E_ID IS NULL AND F_NAME IS NULL AND CITY IS NULL THEN 'INSERT' 
END FLAG
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use IIF or DECODE functions in Informatica.

```
DECODE(TRUE, 
E_ID = EMP_ID AND F_NAME = FIRST_NAME AND CITY = LOCATION, 'REJECT',
IS_NULL(E_ID) AND IS_NULL(F_NAME) AND IS_NULL(CITY),'INSERT')
```